# Glitches in the image is observed after converting binary data into an Image using python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv, wxwidgets

> I have video file in .bin format of frame resolution width=1280 and height=672.I have converted that binary data into an RGB format then re-scaling(width=900 & height=600) and through wxImage viewer window it is displayed.

```
    def ret_frame(self, e, frame_num):

        self.total_frames, f
        #Reading a frame size data
        self.uyvy_size = self.img_height * self.img_width * 2

        assert (frame_num <= self.total_frames and frame_num >= 1), "frame number not in range"

        f.seek(self.uyvy_size * (frame_num - 1), os.SEEK_SET)
        uyvy = np.fromfile(f, count=self.uyvy_size, dtype=np.uint8)

        #String each uyvy component into a separate numpy array
        u = uyvy[::4].astype(dtype=np.float32)
        y1 = uyvy[1::4].astype(dtype=np.float32)
        v = uyvy[2::4].astype(dtype=np.float32)
        y2 = uyvy[3::4].astype(dtype=np.float32)
        #Logic to convert uyvy into rgb
        r1 = ((y1 + ((1.4065) * (v - 128))) * 0.85).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
        g1 = (((y1 - ((0.3455) * (u - 128)) - (0.7169 * (v - 128)))) * 0.85).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
        b1 = (((y1 + ((1.7790) * (u - 128)))) * 0.85).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
        r1[r1 > 255] = 255
        g1[r1 > 255] = 255
        b1[r1 > 255] = 255

        r1[r1 < 0] = 0
        g1[r1 < 0] = 0
        b1[r1 < 0] = 0

        r2 = (((y2 + ((1.4065) * (v - 128)))) * 0.85).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
        g2 = (((y2 - ((0.3455) * (u - 128)) - (0.7169 * (v - 128)))) * 0.85).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
        b2 = (((y2 + ((1.7790) * (u - 128)))) * 0.85).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
        r2[r2 > 255] = 255
        g2[r2 > 255] = 255
        b2[r2 > 255] = 255

        r2[r2 < 0] = 0
        g2[r2 < 0] = 0
        b2[r2 < 0] = 0

        img = np.dstack((r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2))

        self.image = wx.Image(self.img_width, self.img_height, img)
        #OpenCV show is used to clear the buffer otherwise after showing some frame ,the framework crashes
        dummy_img = np.zeros((0, 0, 3))
        cv2.imshow("asdf", 0)
        #Rescaling the image into smaller size image
        self.image = self.image.Rescale(900, 600, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(self.image))
```

Comment: Some small red/pink color dots is observed in the displayed image.

Comment: When you create `r1`, `g1` and `b1`, you make them `uint8`. You then check if they are greater than 255 or less than zero which cannot be with `uint8`... I think you need to clamp to 0..255 later.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for the reply. Yes you are correct i have typecasted r1,g1 and b1 into unit8. So there is no need to check for greater than 255 and less than 0. I have tried removal of clamping logic and performing clamping logic later  but glitches remains in the image.Please let me know what else can be done.